# Password authentication failed- postgis/postgresql database to use geodjango

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm following the geodjango tutorial here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#introduction

I successfully completed the installation/setup.

When I try entering the first command at the command line:

createdb -T template_postgis geodjango

I get this error message:

createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mss"

mss is my windows username.
Should I be using the password I entered when I installed postgresql?  The default username during the install was postgres... so in that case how do I change the username?

Thanks for your help!!

(I'm on Windows XP)

Comment: Not a full blown answer but a hint: In the referenced tutorial `su` and `sudo` are used for executing shell commands with other user rights - `postgres` in this case. AFAIK on Windows this can be done with the `runas` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *so in that case how do I change the username?*

Use the -U switch as documented in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html):

```
createdb -U postgres -T template_postgis geodjango
```

The `-U` switch is used in all Postgres command line applications to specify the username. You will also need this for `psql` to run interactive queries (unless you use a different SQL tool)